# QGIS: get unique values of chosen attributes when editing layer style

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

In order to style a map comprised by OSM data (shapefiles), I want to use rule-based style.
This is very handy, however: the data has so many attributes with lots of values that I somehow loose the overview.

Suppose I want to style different road types. In the properties window, I open the "fields" tab to see my options. I decide that I want to style according to the field "highway". Is there a way to see the possible values for this attribute without opening the attribute table? What I want to see is something like a list

- primary
- secondary
- tertiary
- motorway
- residential
- ...

This could enable making good and fast decisions on layer styles.
If there is such an option, I hope someone can indicate it.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment, @Joseph. I wonder if there is a possibility to see the unique values when editing the style properties? Using the field calculator, I can open either one or the other window which is not so very helpful.

Comment: Most welcome, will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the unique values for fields whilst editing your When you edit a rule, click the **ellipses** button for the *Filter* option. This opens up the expression string builder (which has a very similar interface like the Field Calculator). Again, you can select the `Fields and Values` list and load all unique values:

[image: Editing rule]

[image: Unique values]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. When I opened the field calculator or the filter option, the right section wasn't visible. It opened by clicking on the right edge of the window and moving left.

Comment: @yenats - Most welcome, glad it helped! Yes...the closed tab can be quite annoying :)